# User imageURL is nil on the latest StreamChatUI Swift SDK '4.0.0-beta.11'

Tags: swift

It looks like coding key for user's image url is wrong now,

see

```
enum UserPayloadsCodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
    case id
    case name
    case imageURL = "image"
```

I think it should be `image_url` instead

thank you,

Comment: Is there a question? Maybe you should ask on their GitHub repo instead? What does say their changelog btw? https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift

Comment: It seems to have been updated there https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift/blob/ffea99217e99ca1652ed4c972c232f2f5989e7f4/Sources/StreamChat/WebSocketClient/WebSocketConnectPayload.swift So maybe not everywhere. Fill a ticket on the repo